# .Net Core 2.0 Angular SPA Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I recently generated a new Angular SPA project from the .Net core 2.0 SPA templates. I am new to Angular/Typescript and HMR which I think might be part of the problem.

Mostly everything has been working for a while until recently I noticed that if I refresh any page with F5 or manually type in a URL I get a white page with the word "Value" written. Basically, the only way I am able to route my page is by clicking on the links on my nav bar. I have MCV views that I want to go to that manage users, products, and roles. The way I get there is by manually typing in the URL example

I type in 'localhost:53212/roles' and I get that value page. Also, on any SPA view, if I hit refresh f5, I get the same white page with value. After inspecting the page with value in the chrome debugger I noticed it is wrapped in a 'pre' tag which when I do a search, is found in the Vendor.js file and when I navigate to all the instances of 'pre' I get this code

```
/**
```

* A regular expression for breaking a URI into its component parts.
 *
 * {\@link http://www.gbiv.com/protocols/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#RFC2234} says
 * As the "first-match-wins" algorithm is identical to the "greedy"
 * disambiguation method used by POSIX regular expressions, it is natural and
 * commonplace to use a regular expression for parsing the potential five
 * components of a URI reference.
 *
 * The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
 * well-formed URI reference into its components.
 *
 *

```
 * ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]))?([^?#])(\?([^#]))?(#(.))?
 *  12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
 *
```

*
 * The numbers in the second line above are only to assist readability; they
 * indicate the reference points for each subexpression (i.e., each paired
 * parenthesis). We refer to the value matched for subexpression  as $.
 * For example, matching the above expression to
 *

```
 *     http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
 *
```

* results in the following subexpression matches:
 *

```
 *    $1 = http:
 *    $2 = http
 *    $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
 *    $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
 *    $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
 *    $6 = 
 *    $7 = 
 *    $8 = #Related
 *    $9 = Related
 *
```

* where  indicates that the component is not present, as is the
 * case for the query component in the above example. Therefore, we can
 * determine the value of the five components as
 *

```
 *    scheme    = $2
 *    authority = $4
 *    path      = $5
 *    query     = $7
 *    fragment  = $9
 *
```

*
 * The regular expression has been modified slightly to expose the
 * userInfo, domain, and port separately from the authority.
 * The modified version yields
 *

```
 *    $1 = http              scheme
 *    $2 =        userInfo -\
 *    $3 = www.ics.uci.edu   domain     | authority
 *    $4 =        port     -/
 *    $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/    path
 *    $6 =        query without ?
 *    $7 = Related           fragment without #
 *
```

I don't really understand what all this means or if it is relevant. I also think it might HMR but again, really new to this and cant understand why refresh or manual routing would cause a problem

Thanks for any help, I can provide more info as needed, just didn't want to overwhelm with information and not even be on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this issue out. The hot module reloading was effecting the F5 refreshing issue. If I disable I the HMR then F5 refresh works. For some reason I though the HMR was effecting the MVC views but it was not, the simple solution to that is down below.

As for the MVC portion of the views I did not have the proper route. The configured route is {controller}/{action} and I was just typing in the controller.

If anyone else has some insight, I would love to hear it!

Thanks